# Solving a one-dimensional free-boundary problem with a singular boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-conditions

**Addendum (orginial question below).** Thank you for the responses! After thinking some more about this problem, and thanks to @bbgodfreys helpful comment, I realised that the problem as posted below is incomplete. What I need instead is to find $R$ and $f$ such that

1. $f(R) = g(\lambda R)$,
2. $f'(R) = g'(\lambda R)$,
3. $\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r f'(r)}{f(r)} = -\gamma$, and

$f$ also satisfies the ODE below. This leads to two questions.

**Q1.** Which two conditions I should pass to `NDSolve`, and which one should be the focus of the `FindRoot` operation? Further, what is the correct way to pass condition 3 to `NDSolve`?

**Q2.** In either case, the small-$r$ limit and corresponding singularity of $f$ in condition 3 makes life difficult - what is the best way to deal with this?

Perhaps Q1 is not so critical - Q2 seems to me to be the bottleneck. My current attempt, using the methods in the answers below, is to pass conditions 1 and 2 to `NDSolve`, and use `FindRoot` for condition 3. I have however been unsuccessul thus far. To wit, if I set $r = 0$ as the left boundary of `NDSolve`, I first of all get the expected warning

```
NDSolveValue::ndsz: At r == 1.2839295947759316`*^-19, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

This sets a lower bound on $r$ for `FindRoot`, since I assume from the warning above that I am not to trust the solution for $r < 10^{-19}$. I hence have to make an ad hoc choice for `FindRoot` for condition 3, for example,

```
trig = R/.FindRoot[
  -\[Gamma] - (r Derivative[1][solver[R]][r])/solver[R][r] /. CONS /. 
   r -> 10^-15,
  {R, (1/100/1000)/5}
  ][[1]]

(* 4.28145*10^-15 *)
```

I am unconvinced by `FindRoot`'s solution, since (i) it seems to depend on my ad hoc choice for "$r \to 0$", and (ii) doesn't seem to perform well anyway:

```
sol = solver[trig]

-\[Gamma] - (r Derivative[1][sol][r])/sol[r] /. CONS /. r -> 10^-15
(* 0.0230768 *)
```

I'm aware that this addendum significantly alters the question - my apologies! Would be grateful for any suggestions on how to proceed from here. Thanks again for your help thus far.

---

**Original question.** I have the following ODE for $f(r)$:

```
pdef = 2 (\[Beta] f[r] + 
r (-\[Mu] + \[Rho]) Derivative[1][f][
      r] + ((-1)^(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma])) r^((
     2 \[Gamma])/(-1 + \[Gamma])) (-1 + \[Gamma]) \
\[Zeta]^(-(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma]))) \[Rho]^(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \
\[Gamma]))
      Derivative[1][f][r]^(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma])))/\[Gamma]) == 
 r^2 \[Sigma]^2 (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r]
```

I am looking for an $R > 0$ such that for the following known function $g$,

```
g[r_] := (2^(1 - \[Gamma]) (1/
  r)^\[Gamma] \[Eta]^\[Gamma] \[Rho]^-\[Gamma] ((-2 \[Beta] + \
\[Gamma] (-2 \[Mu] + 
      2 \[Rho] + (1 + \[Gamma]) \[Sigma]^2))/(-1 + \[Gamma]))^(-1 + \
\[Gamma]))/\[Gamma]
```

we have $f(R) = g(\lambda R)$, and $f'(R) = g'(\lambda R)$ for $\lambda$ a constant. Further, for $r < R$, we must have $f(r) > g(r)$, as well as $\lim_{r \to\ 0} f(r) = \infty$

Since I do not know $R$, my idea is to wrap `NDSolve` in `FindRoot` as follows. First, for some guess $R$, define

```
solver[R_?NumericQ] := NDSolveValue[{
   pdef /. CONS,
   DirichletCondition[f[r] == g[\[Lambda] r] /. CONS, r == R]
   },
  f,
  {r, R/10, R}
  ]
```

where

```
CONS = {\[Rho] -> 0.02, 
  J -> 5, \[Gamma] -> 0.5, \[Mu] -> 0.03, \[Sigma] -> 0.2, \[Zeta] -> 
   0.5, \[Beta] -> 0.012, k -> 10, \[Eta] -> 0.8, \[Lambda] -> 1.03}
```

is a set of constants. Then use `FindRoot` to ensure that the condition on the derivative is specified:

```
FindRoot[
  Derivative[1][solver[R]][R] - D[g[\[Lambda] R], R] /. CONS,
  {R, 1/100000}
  ]
```

However, I run into trouble with my function `solver`, which gives me the error message

```
DiscretizePDE::femdpop: The FEMLoadElements operator failed.
```

A plot shows that the solution, instead of "shooting" up and above the orange curve, collapses to the $r$-axis.

[image]

What is wrong with my `NDSolve` setup? I would be grateful for any suggestions on how to improve my approach or attack the problem with an alternative method.

*PS.* I have resorted to the above since I simply could not understand how to implement `NeumannValue` for this problem. I was also unsuccessful in implementing `Method -> "Shooting"` with the smooth fit conditions: the solution "collapsed" just as above, leading me to believe that the derivative condition was simply being ignored when shooting.

Comment: Because `pdef` is a second order ODE, NDSolve requires that two boundary conditions be specified.  One of them clearly is `f[R]`.  Since `f'[R]` is to be used to determine `R`. it cannot be used for `NDSolve`.  This suggests that a boundary condition very near `r = 0` be specified.  This, in turn, requires that an asymptotic solution be determined there, perhaps i the form of a power series.

Comment: Perhaps, `r*f'[r]/f[r] == -1/2` for very small `r` could be the inner boundary condition.

Comment: @bbgodfrey You're absolutely correct that a third boundary condition is necessary; in fact, this is what makes the free-boundary problem overdetermined. But I wasn't sure how to deal numerically with $\lim_{r \to 0} f(r) = \infty$; how did you derive the boundary condition that you suggest?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Another follow-up question: how does one implement a condition like `r*f'[r]/f[r] == -1/2` in `NDSolve`?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply.  I shall not have much time to work on this until late today.  I obtained the small-r boundary conditin by expanding the ODE there and keeping the leading term, which is proportional to `1/Sqrt[r]`/  In p rinciple, you can simply insert the equation in my last comment into `NDSolve`.  However, I encountered overflow errors after doing so, which I need to investigate.

Comment: I continue to think about your question but do not yet have an answer.  However, I can say that (1) you should disregard my comment about `r*f'[r]/f[r] == -1/2` and (2) the answer by jdp is wrong.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for continuing to think about this. Why do you say that I should disregard your comment about `r*f'[r]/f[r] == -1/2`? I think that this equation is correct, and it matches my intuition about how $f$ should behave in this limit.

Comment: Does my answer below indicate why I have abandoned `-1/2`` as the proper limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question's ode with the given constants, rationalized, is

```
pdfc = 2 ((3 f[r])/250 + 25/(r^2 f'[r]) - 1/100 r f'[r]) == 1/25 r^2 f''[r]
```

and the function `g` is `200/Sqrt[r]`.  Answering the question is difficult, because the ode has an essential singularity at `r = 0`, and `Limit[r f'[r]/f[r], r->0]` can have multiple values.

**Approximate symbolic solution of pdfc**

Some insight can be gained, however, by obtaining an approximate solution to the ODE, obtained by dropping the term `25/(r^2 f'[r])`.

```
sa = DSolveValue[2 ((3 f[r])/250 - 1/100 r f'[r]) == 1/25 r^2 f''[r], f[r], r]
(* r^(1/2 (1/2 - Sqrt[53/5]/2)) C[1] + r^(1/2 (1/2 + Sqrt[53/5]/2)) C[2] *)
```

The two exponents have numerical values `{-0.563941, 1.06394}`.  If, then, `f[r]` is set equal to the first exponential, it is easy to show that the term `25/(r^2 f'[r])` indeed can be ignored for very small `r`.  The same is not true of the second exponential, which should be dropped (e.g., `C[2] = 0`) from the approximate solution.  Consequently, this solution satisfies the limit,

```
Limit[r f'[r]/f[r], r->0] = 1/4 (1 - Sqrt[53/5])
```

Interesting, an exact solution also exists, `c/Sqrt[r]`, with `{c -> -50 Sqrt[10], c -> 50 Sqrt[10]}`.

```
Simplify[pdfc /. f -> Function[{r}, -50 Sqrt[10]/Sqrt[r]]]
(* True *)
```

and similarly for the second value of `c`.  As will become apparent below, this solution is not of much value.    For completeness, this solution has the small `r` limit,

```
Limit[r f'[r]/f[r], r->0] = -1/2
```

There may be other symbolic solutions, but I have been unable to find any.

**Numerical solutions**

Obtaining numerical solutions may seem straightforward: With initial conditions, `{f[rm] == g[1.03 rm], f'[rm] == g'[1.03 rm]}`, integrate toward `r = 0`.  However, integrating toward an essential singularity invites numerical errors.  So, I first integrated to a very small value of `r0 = 10^-30` and then integrated back again to `rm` to ascertain whether the same values of `{f[rm], f'[rm]} resulted.  It turned out that very high precision was required.  For instance,

```
r0 = 10^-30; rm = 1; wp = 150;
s1 = NDSolveValue[{pdfc, f[rm] == 200/Sqrt[103/100 rm], 
    f'[rm] == -100/Sqrt[103/100 rm]^3}, {f[r], f[r0], f'[r0]}, {r, r0, rm}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> wp, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
    InterpolationOrder -> All];
s2 = NDSolveValue[{pdfc, f[r0] == SetPrecision[s1[[2]], wp], 
    f'[r0] == SetPrecision[s1[[3]], wp]}, {f[r], f[rm], f'[rm]}, {r, r0, rm}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> wp, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
    InterpolationOrder -> All];
```

A measure of the accuracy of the calculation is

```
{s2[[2]]/g[103/100 rm]) - 1, s2[[3]]/g'[103/100 rm] - 1} // N
(* {-6.2683*10^-29, 1.27023*10^-28} *)
```

(Smaller values of `wp` often perform much less well.)  The curves themselves are shown by

```
LogLogPlot[{First[s1], g[r], First[s2]}, {r, r0, rm}, 
    AxesLabel -> {r, "f,g"}, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

where the blue and green curves (superimposed) are the inward and outward numerical integrations, and the orange curve is `g[r]`.  More informative is a plot of `r f'[r]/f[r]`.

```
LogLinearPlot[Evaluate[r D[s2[[1]], r]/s2[[1]]], {r, r0, rm}, 
    AxesLabel -> {r, "r f'/f"}, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

which converges to `-0.564` for very small `r`, as might be expected from the symbolic analysis above.  Note that the numerical calculation takes several minutes on my pc. Thus, if this is accepted as the desired `r = 0` limit, then `rm = 1` satisfies the question.  In fact, every value of `rm` I have tried does so, and in each case `Limit[r f'[r]/f[r], r->0]` converges to the same value.  Curves for `rm = {10^-5, 1, 10^5}` are

[image]

In no case did `r f'[r]/f[r]` converge to `-1/2`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this comprehensive and clear answer. Do I understand correctly that your conclusion is the same as Alex's above, namely, that the problem as posed does not admit a unique solution?

Comment: @Anthony Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks, this whole discussion has been enlightening. I'll have to think hard about my problem in order to understand what condition I need to impose in order to obtain a unique solution.

Answer (score 4):

I'm more accustomed to working in a slightly different format, but this should be equivalent to what you're doing. Define functions to build the pdes and g:

```
pdef[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_, \[Sigma]_, \[Mu]_, \[Rho]_, \[Zeta]_] := 
  2 \[Beta] f[r] + 
    2 r (-\[Mu] + \[Rho]) f'[
      r] + (2 (-1)^(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma])) r^((2 \[Gamma])/(-1 + \
\[Gamma])) (-1 + \[Gamma]) \[Zeta]^(-(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma]))) \
\[Rho]^(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma])) f'[
         r]^(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma])))/\[Gamma] - 
    r^2 \[Sigma]^2 f''[r] == 0;

g[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_, \[Mu]_, \[Eta]_, \[Rho]_, \[Sigma]_, \
\[Lambda]_][
   r_] := (2^(1 - \[Gamma]) (1/
        r)^\[Gamma] \[Eta]^\[Gamma] \[Rho]^-\[Gamma] ((-2 \[Beta] + \
\[Gamma] (-2 \[Mu] + 
             2 \[Rho] + (1 + \[Gamma]) \[Sigma]^2))/(-1 + \
\[Gamma]))^(-1 + \[Gamma]))/\[Gamma];
```

The solver with most of the constants plugged in. (You don't seem to use J or k for anything as far as I can tell.)

```
solver[rSol_?NumericQ] := 
  NDSolve[{pdef[0.012, 1/2, 0.2, 0.03, 0.02, 1/2], 
    f[rSol] == g[0.012, 1/2, 0.03, 0.8, 0.02, 0.2, 1.03][rSol], 
    Derivative[1][f][rSol] == 
     Derivative[1][g[0.012, 1/2, 0.03, 0.8, 0.02, 0.2, 1.03]][rSol]}, 
   f, {r, rSol/10, rSol}];
```

The main difference is that I removed the Dirichlet code and just used a simple f[rSol] = g[..][rSol] and the corresponding derivatives directly, using the conditions you wrote in the text.

FindRoot complained about the solution being non-numeric, so I created an auxillary function to keep it happy:

```
rsf[rs_?NumericQ] := 
  Derivative[1][f][rs] /. Flatten@solver[rs];
```

I changed the constant to a value different from yours, to verify that it did indeed search for the root:

```
FindRoot[
 rsf[rSol] - 
  Derivative[1][g[0.012, 1/2, 0.03, 0.8, 0.02, 0.2, 1.03]][
   rSol], {rSol, .0002(*1/100000*)}]

Out[39]= {rSol -> 0.00001}
```

I reran once last time to generate plots and verify other conditions. The output was of the form {f->InterpolatingFunction[..]}, which I won't copy here since it's long and ugly.

```
nds = Flatten@solver[.00001]
```

Here are f,g, and f-g:

[image: Plot of f,g,f-g]

Since the scales are quite different, here's f-g alone:

[image: Plot of f-g alone]

Here's f'[r]

[[image: f'r]

And here are {{f[rSol],g[rSol]}{f'[rSol],g'[rSol]}}. f,g and f',g' are equal at rSol, as required.

```
{f[r] /. nds, 
   g[0.012, 1/2, 0.03, 0.8, 0.02, 0.2, 1.03][r]}, {f'[r] /. nds, 
   D[g[0.012, 1/2, 0.03, 0.8, 0.02, 0.2, 1.03][r], r]}} /. 
 r -> 9.999999999999999`*^-6

Out[53]= {{63245.6, 63245.6}, {-3.16228*10^9, -3.16228*10^9}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer! I need to play with it for a little bit. Your method of simply using `Derivative[1][f]...` in `NDSolve` already helps a great deal. One comment: in your  definition of `rsf`, I assume that the `10^-5` should be replaced with `rs`?

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I've updated the question, which was incompletely posed; would be great if you had any further ideas.

Comment: When I run your code, `FindRoot`  returns as an answer whatever initial guess I give it, as it must for the definition of `solver`. in your code.

Answer (score 4):

We can map $(0, R)$ on $(0,1)$ using substitution $r\rightarrow R r$, and use `ParametricNDSolveValue` as follows

```
eq = 2 (\[Beta] f[r] + 
      r (-\[Mu] + \[Rho]) f'[
        r] + ((-1)^(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma])) (R r)^((2 \[Gamma])/(-1 \
+ \[Gamma])) (-1 + \[Gamma]) \[Zeta]^(-(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma]))) \
\[Rho]^(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma])) (f'[r]/
            R)^(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma])))/\[Gamma]) - 
   r^2 \[Sigma]^2 f''[r];


CONS = {\[Rho] -> 0.02, 
  J -> 5, \[Gamma] -> 0.5, \[Mu] -> 0.03, \[Sigma] -> 0.2, \[Zeta] -> 
   0.5, \[Beta] -> 0.012, k -> 10, \[Eta] -> 0.8, \[Lambda] -> 1.03}; 
g[r_] := (2^(1 - \[Gamma]) (1/R/
        r)^\[Gamma] \[Eta]^\[Gamma] \[Rho]^-\[Gamma] ((-2 \[Beta] + \
\[Gamma] (-2 \[Mu] + 
             2 \[Rho] + (1 + \[Gamma]) \[Sigma]^2))/(-1 + \
\[Gamma]))^(-1 + \[Gamma]))/\[Gamma] /. CONS;

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq == 0, f[1] == g[\[Lambda]], 
    f'[1] == \[Lambda] g'[\[Lambda]]} /. CONS, f, {r, 10^-3, 1}, {R}];
```

Visualization numerical solution (solid line) and function $g(\lambda r)$ (dashed red line) for  `R=0.5,1,1.5,2`

```
Table[Show[
  LogLogPlot[sol[R][r], {r, 10^-3, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotLabel -> R, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {{0.001, 1}, Automatic}}], 
  LogLogPlot[g[\[Lambda] r] /. CONS, {r, 10^-3, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]], {R, .5, 2, .5}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

**Update 1.** To satisfier condition at $r\rightarrow 0$ we suppose that $f(r)=a/r^{\gamma}$, and using `eq` we can define `a` as follows

```
rule = {f[r] -> a/r^\[Gamma] , f'[r] -> -\[Gamma]  a/r^(\[Gamma] + 1),
    f''[r] -> \[Gamma]  (\[Gamma] + 1) a/r^(\[Gamma] + 2)};

eq /. rule /. \[Gamma] -> 1/2 // FullSimplify; sl = Solve[% == 0, a];
```

Then we define function

```
f0 = a/r^\[Gamma] /. sl[[2]] /. CONS

Out[]= 158.114/(r^0.5 Sqrt[R])
```

Analyzing picture above we can suggest that function `f0+b`, where `b` is some constantan, should correlate with solution `sol`. To verifier this suggestion we use `NMinimize` as follows

```
eqn = (f0 + b - sol1[R][r]) /. r -> 10^-3;

 NMinimize[{eqn^2, {R > 0}}, {R, b}]

(*Out[]= {2.42103*10^-14, {R -> 138.914, b -> 215.84}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've updated the question, which was incompletely posed; would be great if you had any further ideas.

Comment: @Anthony Please, see update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, and sorry for taking a few days to get back to you. I'm just parsing through the logic of your answer, and have a rather simple question to begin with: why is the mapping $r \mapsto Rr$ useful? I am also wondering how exactly you obtained `eq`: did you do something like `pdef /. r -> Rr`? Because if so, I get a different expression for `eq` than you do.

Comment: @Anthony Could you show your expression `eq`?

Comment: Sure thing: `2 \[Beta] f[r R] + (
  2 (-1)^(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma])) (r R)^((
   2 \[Gamma])/(-1 + \[Gamma])) (-1 + \[Gamma]) \
\[Zeta]^(-(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma]))) \[Rho]^(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \
\[Gamma]))
    Derivative[1][f][r R]^(\[Gamma]/(-1 + \[Gamma])))/\[Gamma] == 
 r R (2 (\[Mu] - \[Rho]) Derivative[1][f][r R] + 
    r R \[Sigma]^2 (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r R])`

Comment: @Anthony No, it is not a right expression `eq` in a new coordinate. The goal of mapping is function $f(r), 0\le r\le 1$, while your function  `f[r R]` still defined on $0\le r \le R$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, that makes sense: I was able to reproduce `eq` using the function `DSolveChangeVariables`. The one other question I had is that the solution above is highly dependent on the value of `r` used in `eqn` (in your case `10^-3`): if I change this to `10^-10`, `NMinimize` yields `{2.5047*10^-13, {R -> 83341.6, b -> 130222.}}` My explanation is that this is expected behaviour since the analyst has to decide what the limit $r \to 0$ means in practice. Does this match your intuition?

Comment: @Anthony For my opinion it means that your problem has no unique solution.